# Bifurcation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

I am having trouble understanding the concept of bifurcation. Can someone help me understand $ 1b $ and $ 1c $ in this [example?](https://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/M5410_M1_practice.pdf) I understand to the point that in order to find the bifurcation, I need to solve $ ax + \sin x = 0, $ but I don't understand the next paragraph:

> The bifurcation diagram are the solutions of $ \displaystyle a +
> \frac{\sin x}{x} = 0, $ which are plotted as the blue and red curves. It shows how as a departs from $ a = 0 $ and moves to $ |a| = 1, $ there are fewer and fewer rest points that such that sources and sinks cancel pairwise as $ |a| $ increases. For $ a > −1 $ near $ a = −1, $ there are only three rest points which collapse to one in a pitchfork bifurcation at $ x = 0 $ and $ a = −1. $ After $ |a| \ge 1 $ there is only one rest point at $ 0. $

Answer (score 1):

At a bifurcation point, two or more of the solution curves parametrized by $a$ meet. Which means that there is a multiple solution. Which means that additionally to $f_a(x)=0$ one also has $f_a'(x)=0$ satisfied. Here that means that simultaneously
$$
0=ax+\sin(x)\\0=a+\cos(x)
$$
Eliminating $a$ gives the equation $x=\tan(x)$ and every solution $x^*$ of that gives a bifurcation point with $a^*=-\cos(x^*)$.